# Salesforce SAML Assertion flow via REST API for Lightning Out

Tags: rest-api, single-sign-on, saml, lightning-out, azure-active-directory

Context: We want to log a user into a Lightning Out App hosted on an Azure AD System using the SAML Assertion flow.

What we have establisched so far:

- We have a functioning connection for our Salesforce and a Saleforce Community on the same platform as Service Providers, Azure being the Identity provider via SAML 2.0.
- This connection is working in UI, so on the respective login pages the Users can log into Salesforce using a single button click if they already have arunning Azure AD Session

Problem: 
We want to have Azure log into Salesforce using this connection via Rest API. This will yield an access_token. We need the access token for the Lightning Out App to function.

We are following this documentation:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_sso_flow.htm&type=5

How do we initiate this interview from Azure? I.e. how do we generate the SAML Assertion Response?

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish? Please edit your question.

Comment: @identigral Hi, as requested I have editet the question.